# teradata gaps between previous date and preceding date by date by employee

Tags: teradata, teradatasql

I want to get the gap time between records and make that a row.

first record Joe StartDate 5/23/21 8:46 AM EndDate 5/23/21 9 AM,

next record Joe start date 5/23/21 9:23 AM End Date 5/23/21 10:43 AM,

next record Joe start date 5/23/21 8:23 AM End Date 5/23/21 2:01 PM,

next record Joe start date 5/23/21 11:16 AM End Date 5/23/21 2:54 PM,

next record Joe start date 5/23/21 11:26 AM End Date 5/23/21 3:14 PM,

next record Joe start date 5/12/2022 10:17:47 AM End Date 5/12/20224:45:54 PM,

next record Suzy start date 5/2/2022 8:08:26 AM End Date  5/2/2022 2:01:07 PM,

next record Suzy start date 5/1/2022 2:33:09 PM End Date 5/1/2022 2:49:53 PM,

next record Suzy start date 5/1/2022 2:35:02 PM End Date 5/11/2022 3:14:33 PM,

next record Suzy start date 5/12/2022 10:39:23 AM End Date 5/12/2022 4:49:33 PM,

next record JuJu start date 5/2/2022 11:03:14 AM End Date 5/2/2022 1:06:34 PM,

next record JuJu start date 5/2/2022 11:17:26 AM End Date 5/2/2022 1:31:33 PM,

next record JuJu start date 5/2/2022 11:41:12 AM End Date 5/2/2022 1:48:16 PM

I've tried:
'code' Lag(STARTDATE) Over (PARTITION BY ASSIGNEDTO, STARTDATE ORDER BY ASSIGNEDTO,STARTDATE,ENDDATE) AS prev_date,
Max(EndDate) Over (PARTITION BY ASSIGNEDTO, EndDate ORDER BY ASSIGNEDTO, EndDate DESC) AS max_start,'code'

Sometimes there's no end date, so that's why I am trying to get the time between the start and end date and the start date previous record and start date of current record, but i also need to see if folks are down and not doing anything? So I have two calculations 1 for HTM = total time from start to End and another that should show time between task or records for that date by employee.
'code'
EXAMPLE RECORD:
ASSIGNEDTO  AUDITDATETIME   STARTDATE               ENDDATE                 TASKNAME

Joe 12/10/2021 12:00:00 AM  12/10/2021 4:42:05 PM   12/10/2021 6:10:48   PM Case Review

jUjU    5/17/2022 12:00:00 AM   5/17/2022 10:50:07   AM null    Initial Review

jUjU    5/17/2022 12:00:00 AM   5/17/2022 12:03:06   AM null    Initial Review

Here I have to calculate between the 5/17 10:50 and 12:03 indicates
she completed it in hh.mm
BeBe    11/12/2021 12:00:00 AM  11/2/2021 9:23:31 AM    11/2/2021 12:38:25 PM   Manual

BeBE    11/2/2021 12:00:00 AM   11/2/2021 4:04:16 PM    11/2/2021   4:15:09 PM  Case Review

Here I have to show the gap time between 12:38PM and 4:04 PM

Comment: Can you format your question, try to add the data in tabular format. It is very difficult to concentrate on the question with lot of text. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277716/how-can-i-create-a-table-in-a-post

Comment: | LID | ASSIGNEDTO |11 AUDITDATETIME |10 STARTDATE |9 ENDDATE |8 TASKNAME |7 Function |6 NUMBER |5 PRODUCT |4 TYPE |3 PRIORITY |2 TYPE2 |2 <br/>
| 52116 | Joem | 5/10/22 12:00 AM | 5/10/22 11:29 AM | 5/10/22 11:29 AM | Initial Review | Motor Install | A2213196882 | Ford | F150 | Standard | 5 Speed | <br/>
| 52118 | Joem | 5/11/22 12:00 AM | 5/11/22 11:20 AM | 5/11/22 3:09 PM | Initial Review | Motor Install | A2213181875 | Ford | F150 | Standard | 5 Speed | <br/>

Comment: Name | Start Date | End Date | Task
  |  Joe | 5/23/21 8:46 AM | 5/23/21 9 AM  | Case Review
  |  Joe | 5/23/21 9:23 AM | 5/23/21 10:43 AM | Case Review
  |  Joe | 5/23/21 8:23 AM |  |  5/23/21 2:01 PM | Initial Review
  |  Joe  |  5/23/21 11:16 AM  |  5/23/21 2:54 PM | Manual
  |  Joe  |  5/23/21 11:26 AM  |  5/23/21 3:14 PM | Initial Review
  |  Joe  |  5/12/2022 10:17:47 AM  |  5/12/20224:45:54 PM |  Initial Review
  |  Suzy  |  5/2/2022 8:08:26 AM  |  5/2/2022 2:01:07 PM | Manual
  |  Suzy  |  5/1/2022 2:33:09 PM  |  5/1/2022 2:49:53 PM | Manual

Comment: So if I understand it correct, you want to find the difference between current row ENDDATE and next row STARTDATE, If END DATE is null then difference between current row STARTDATE and next row STARTDATE for the Same Person on the same Day.

Comment: Will there be any cases when a task starts on one day and completes on another day? In that case for which DATE the difference should be calculated? Ex:  `|Suzy | 5/1/2022 2:33:09 PM | 5/3/2022 2:49:53 PM | Manual|
|Suzy | 5/4/2022 8:08:26 AM | 5/4/2022 2:01:07 PM | Manual | `

Comment: Finally someone understands me. Yes sir its possible they could stop a task and then pick it up the same day or even the next day. I know i'm making this harder than what it has to be. My idea here is to show, ok, this is the time they spent on the task, and here is the time between each task they completed for that day. to show their down time.

Comment: The case when there is no end date, what will be the time spent on task? Ex. `|Suzy | 5/1/2022 2:33:09 PM | null | Manual
|Suzy | 5/4/2022 8:08:26 AM | null | Manual`

Comment: The question is still not clear to me, But you can start with below query to see if it works.          
` SELECT
Name
StartDate
,EndDate
,Task
,LEAD(StartDate,1,StartDate) OVER(PARTITION BY Name,Cast(StartDate as Date) ORDER BY StartDate Asc) as Next_Start_Date
,EndDate-StartDate HOUR TO MINUTE AS Time_Spent_On_Task
,Next_Start_Date-StartDate HOUR TO MINUTE  as Gap_Time
FROM Tab `

Comment: thank you this helped immensly. i think i get stumped on the silliest things.

Comment: I keep getting a "Teradata exception: [Teradata Database] [3504] Selected non-aggregate values must be part of the associated group." It worked well for my one table but not the other.

Comment: Min (Cast (EndDate as TimeStamp)) Over (PARTITION BY ASSIGNEDTO, EndDate ORDER BY ASSIGNEDTO, EndDate DESC) AS min_start,  --- 7
Max (Cast (EndDate as TimeStamp)) Over (PARTITION BY ASSIGNEDTO, EndDate ORDER BY ASSIGNEDTO, EndDate DESC) AS max_start,  --- 8
LEAD(StartDate,1,StartDate) OVER(PARTITION BY UserID,Cast(StartDate as Date) ORDER BY StartDate Asc) as Next_Start_Date , --- 9 group by 1,2,3,6,10,12,13,14,15,16,17,18   I took my Where statement out ive had trouble to get to the root cause.